# How to run different instances of node application

Tags: node.js, express, multiple-instances

I have a node express application exhibiting some web service and maintaning some information about an underlying database and users' environment.
I need to instantiate different instances of the application, all on the same port, connecting each one on a different database, because it will serve a different customer (a customer is an organization  with hundreds of users).
Every customer will be assigned a different code and users of that customers will connect to a different address like:
http:\mainaddress\customerCode\rest_of_address
How is it possible?

[Edit]
We have many customer and we don't want to have a new copy of the entire application for every customer. There must be only one copy of the application.

Comment: create different docker images of your application and deploy them in your server ,each will have their own database

Comment: I read it's not possible for different instances use the same port, and we don't want to duplicate the application files n times